# Basic Pastebin Logging System

Tags: vb.net

I have created a very basic user:pass login system using pastebin.com
I have done this by doing:

```
Dim checker As String = username + ":" + password
Dim login1 As Boolean = ss.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/fikBDHww").Contains(checker)

If login1 = true Then
Console.Writeline("Correct") 
Else
Console.Writeline("Wrong Login")
```

However, I would like to add expiry system with it - how would I read in the expiry date for example: `12:12:2240` in the pastebin with the user:pass as well.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: It's just a string, give it a specific format (e.g., `username:password;2240-12-12`), split on the semi-colon and you have both parts ready to check. The semi-colon is an example, use a separator that is not allowed in the password or username parts.

Comment: I'd suggest using a more structured format such as JSON so you can read each field separately (username, password and expiry). I assume this is just some sort of experiment btw as there is nothing secure about it.